# Magento website down after cache refresh

Tags: magento2, error, cache

This is the error i get when i acces the website:

[Document with the errors - Click here](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1zv6)

### after using the solution given in the first post i get this one now, so it's not the same.

Comment: Hello Welcome to Magento SE, Dont ask single question multiple times

Comment: Run static content deploy for all store.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change developer Mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Follow Below steps

```
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade --- This cmd is related to db changes if 
    you have already done, don't need this.



   php bin/magento setup:di:compile  --- this is use for dependency 
   injection which create class symbolic in generated folder




  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f -- this is used for static content deploy which create files in pub/static/areacode(frontend,adminhtml, customrouter)/packageName/themename/locale code/All static files. -f is needed when you are using developer or default mode.

  But you have give permission after deployment in linux env.
  The Command is chmod 777 -R pub/static/ genarated/ var/


  php bin/magento cache:flush  --`Magento caching system` also permission Needed after flash .
```

***For your case, i think ro_RO/css/config_1.css files not created or you have to check your theme directory exist or not.***